# How to copy existing xlsx column into new column using openpyxl

Tags: python, xlsx, openpyxl

I have an xlsx file and I need add 1 column within openpyxl.
Can you help me pls?

Something like this:

```
wb = load_workbook('wb.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

wb2 = workbook()
ws2 = wb2.active

row = 0

while row < nrows:
        newVal = ws.cell_value(row, 2)
    ws2.write(row, 3, newVal)
    row = row + 1
write_book.save('wb_with_new_column')
```

Comment: What is the particular aspect you're having problems with?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be trying to copy the contents of one column into another column. This can be done easily as follows:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('file1.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

for src, dst in zip(ws['B:B'], ws['C:C']):
    dst.value = src.value

wb.save('file1.xlsx')
```

openpyxl allows you to [iterate over cells](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/tutorial.html#accessing-many-cells). Here we create a source and a destination range of cells to iterate over. `zip()` is used to pair them up, then all that is needed is a simple value copy.